# Fixing The Unfix-able Question

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently asked a bad question, [Ada vs Pascal for General Systems Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531621/ada-vs-pascal-for-general-and-systems-programming). It was closed as an "Opinion Based Question", and I am now question banned.

On the question ban page, It says you should **NOT** delete them, that you should instead fix them. the problem is that there is no way to fix a question like that. It would do me more good to delete myself, seeming as I wouldn't want  to get down-voted farther. The question was asking if Ada or Pascal would be a better choice for systems development and general programming.

I don't see a way to fix a question like this. Can anyone hand me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: I would advise trying to improve your other questions if this one can't be

Comment: I've upvoted [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406898/adding-compilers-on-netbeans) because it's not that terrible I believe. You still have some other questions with a negative score that you can try to improve.

Comment: Is it still acceptable to fix closed questions??

Comment: You can always fix closed questions (and even deleted posts if you can see them).

Comment: @James_Parsons The *purpose* of closing questions is to allow them to be fixed.  *Not* fixing a closed questions is what is undesirable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issues with the types of questions you ask go much deeper than this Ada question. It's just a symptom of a larger problem: It seems like you don't understand the types of questions that are acceptable on Stack Overflow.

I'm going to assume you went through and read the [How to Ask Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) thoroughly, and that we didn't communicate very well what our expectations are.

Let's go over your deleted questions first:

- [Python CGI Problems password sent in plaintext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683312/python-cgi-problems-password-sent-in-plaintext)

  This question wasn't too bad; but it was closed as off topic because the community felt you didn't understand the problem well enough to be able to understand any answer to it.  That particular close reason has been controversial in the past, so I'm re-opening and undeleting your question to give you a chance to address the issues and improve your question.
- [simple 64 bit example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186737/simple-64-bit-binary-example)

  This question was a bit unclear.  What do you need? Why do you need it?  What has kept you from compiling a "Hello World" example on the internet for x64 and then looking at its output in a Hex Editor?  You deleted it, but you didn't have to -- if you could improve the question to address my points above (and even having a specific question about what you need after you've followed the steps I've lined up), it could be a good question.
- [Ada vs Pascal for General Systems Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531621/ada-vs-pascal-for-general-and-systems-programming)

  This question skipped a few hundred logical steps. It essentially says, "I compiled this Ada program, and it was twice as big as my Pascal program, so which one should my team use?"  I hope you've read up on what questions not to ask, because this is definitely off topic as "Primarily opinion based."  You really can't resolve this question because it's just not in scope for this site, no matter what you do.  Again, the How to Ask page would have told you this (I can only assume we didn't communicate that very well. How can we communicate that better?)
- [Need Help on Perl Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205825/need-help-on-perl-program)

  This question suffers from a few problems:

  - The title is very vague.  Can you imagine *anyone* ever typing that title into Google?
  - This question can never be useful because one of the first steps we ask you to take is to actually try to compile the program and run it yourself. Since you can't do that here, you're asking us to do it for you and show you the output.  Since you can't seem to do that here, shouldn't your question be about fixing the issue so that you can compile this program and see its output yourself?

  To improve this question:

  - Fix the title
  - Clean up the spelling and grammatical structure of the post
  - Tell us why you can't compile this, and that should be the focus of the question, not us compiling it for you.
  - If you're encountering an error, make it very clear what the error is; try to run the code with the `-V` syntax and make sure to put `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of your perl script.
- [Getting INI information from perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205062/getting-ini-information-from-perl?noredirect=1)

  This is *almost* a good question.  Some things you could do to make it better:

  - Tell us what you need, what you've tried, and why it's not working.
  - Fix the spelling and grammatical issues in the post. This means to *spend some time improving the text of your post.*
- [Opengl FASM Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204535/opengl-fasm-tutorial)

  The question (Asking for an off site resource) is off topic for our site -- again, I think the How to Ask should have made this clear (but please tell me if it didn't, and how we could improve that messaging). To improve this question, you should do the following:

  - The title needs work.  It should describe your problem as someone who would search for this issue on the internet would look for it.
  - What are you attempting to do? What's not working about it?  Try to implement it, and come in with a specific question (that isn't asking for an off site resource). In this case, it could be something like (don't just use my text):

    > I'm trying to render a triangle using FASM in OpenGL.  Here's the code I have for rendering the triangle below. It doesn't seem to actually render, and this leads me to believe I don't really understand OpenGL FASM rendering. How do I render a triangle in OpenGL using FASM?
- [error in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184744/error-in-javascript)

  Again, the title. Will someone really search for "Error in JavaScript" and expect to find anything meaningful? In this case your error message is more helpful, and that could likely be most of the title. That would make it more useful to future visitors as well (although you're still stuck with the problem that you miss-cased "function", causing your issue.
- [Java + GTK Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096909/java-gtk-hello-world)

  The title is a little better -- but could be expanded. "I need a hello world example in Java and GTK". Besides the title issue; the question itself is a problem. Why is Stack Overflow your first place to go to for this?  I'm sure somewhere on the internet has an example.  If you're having a specific problem with Java and GTK, ask *that* question.

Looking over your questions, here are a few generic pointers:

- Stack Overflow is not a hammer for every programming question in the world.  It feels like you are jumping on Stack Overflow first thing, instead of taking a step back and doing a little bit of research.  It shows in how you ask your questions: Some are rushed and sloppily written, and some just say, "Give this to me."

If there's some messaging we can do to improve why we think your questions were poorly formed or how we could have messaged better on the "How to Ask" and its related pages, let me know. I want that to be as clear as possible.  If however you didn't read it, then you probably should.

I'll see what I can do from my end, but overall, you can fix these issues with your questions, it's just going to take some time, some research, and some improvements in how you phrase your questions.

Good luck.

Comment: A lot of the questions you thought were worse were definitly my earlier. However I must thank you for pointing out that last paragraph. I was trying to use stack overflow for all of my questions. One of the reasons for getting angry at my last question ban was the fact that I had questions I feel could'nt be answered anywhere else. It is also difficult for me now because I see so many web developer and API specific problems.

Comment: @James_Parsons I want to be very clear here: All of the 'gotchas' you've faced with your questions are faced by just about every user who is quality-banned by the system.  I don't want you to be quality banned. I want you to enjoy Stack Overflow. While what I've written may sound harsh, please take it in the spirit it's meant: A set of "What not to dos" so that you don't keep stumbling over the same issues that are causing you to become quality-banned. I want your  questions to be well received. It's not a reflection *on you*. We have years of (everyone) being lazy on the internet to combat.

Comment: So far, I have attempted to fix my grammar on the question on Perl and INI files. My other perl question, the one on "need help" cannot be fixed. I was practicly asking people to run my program for me beacause I was to lazy to figure out why perl was not installing.

Answer (score 3):

No one gets question banned over one question. Improve what you can, ask advice on what you cannot.

The best course of action would be to flag one of your own questions with a custom flag, and ask the moderator to undelete all deleted questions you have because you want to improve them.

After you improve what you can (you need to *seriously* improve though), post here on meta explaining that you've improved your questions and want additional review to get unbanned.

---

Remember that the ban is automatic, no one can magically lift this ban other than yourself using improvement and action.